# Angular - 404 HTTP Interceptor

Tags: angularjs, node.js

Whenever my node server returns a 404 error, I want this to be intercepted by my Angular app and the user directed to a certain route.

I'm trying to build a simple interceptor to do this however it doesn't seem to return anything.

Any pointers on why this code won't print anything when the 404 is coming in (I've confirmed this by looking at the page header):

[image]

And the code:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  //Ignore this authInceptor is for saving my JWT's
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

  //This is the one I'm having issue with
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function myErrorInterceptor($window, $location) {
    return {
      requestError: function(res){
        if (res.status === 404) {
          console.log('You're In - Now do some more stuff')
        }
        return res;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

UPDATE:
So in addition to that, i've realised on my node side - i have

```
//This section is to handle Angular HTML5Mode Urls
//Have to rewrite all your links to entry point of your application (e.g. index.html)
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/site/index.html')
});
```

So another issue here is - that `app.get('/*'` won't be bale to distinguish between whats allowed as per Angular routes - so how do i get it be aware of that? (Don't want something an array where i duplicate code)

Comment: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LvhRC/103/) that might be useful. Also, note the rejected return promises too.

Comment: If you have handled 404/routing all requests back to angular entry point (for HTML5 mode) in the server/node side, in which scenario does it throw 404?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are hooking into `requestError` instead of `responseError`. Try the following:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
  //Ignore this authInceptor is for saving my JWT's
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

  //This is the one I'm having issue with
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function myErrorInterceptor($window, $location) {
    return {
      responseError: function(res){
        if (res.status === 404) {
          console.log('You're In - Now do some more stuff')
        }
        return res;
      }
    }
  })
});
```